# "I need X like this website[link to site], how do?" - when to flag as spam?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam

While reviewing i come across questions that request specific characteristic of some websites with a link to the site.

My first thoughts are, "is this simply an excuse to link to a site he wants to promote"? It could however be someone genuinely trying to solve a problem.

So i flagged it for spam and....

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

What should i do on this type of questions ([and this one in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047445/how-can-i-recreate-this-div-mashup-effect-within-bootstrap))?

Comment: I'd vote to close as too broad if the OP has made no attempt at solving the problem themselves.

Comment: Oh? I most of the time think op just wants this cool jquery slide effect on this awesome new site..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Any question that consists of little more than some lines of text and a link to a website should indeed put you into spam alert mode.

If you actually need to flag it as spam is less clear but here are some tips:

- Check if the website is actually selling something
  The example post you refer to is linking to a venue which is not something you would sell to the masses
- Check if the text is only promoting the product
  The example post is asking for techniques used on that website, it is in no way promoting that website
- Check by using the `url:` search if the link is used in more posts
  The example post is the only one with that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A30eustonsquare.co.uk)
- Check if the user is new or has any other posts already
  The example post is from a fresh user so that is non-decider

I wouldn't have flagged as spam in this case. This doesn't mean that this won't turn out to be spam. We have seen examples where genuine looking posts were a setup to promote a product involving multiple accounts posting and voting on their posts.

Remember that SPAM flags induce a direct penalty of -100 reputation so if that is applied you better make sure it is right. And moderators have some additional technical indicators to judge if something is really spam or not.

In case of doubt you can always drop into a chat room, either in the [SO Tavern](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) or the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) to verify if your suspicion is valid. In any case keep an eye on such posts.

The following actions should be taken on such posts:

- downvote due to lack of research and/or being unclear
- flag to close as unclear
- leave a comment to request clarification, current code status and/or failed attempts to solve the specific need (spammers will not respond)

Comment: Nice, i didnt know i can check for the `url` or asking in specific chatrooms. Would there be any penalties if i flag for `unclear` something that is actually spam (that is, in case i have doubts)?

Comment: @user5061 No penalty. If you are unsure whether a post is spam, but are sure it meets a reason for closing (unclear, too broad, missing code...) then voting/flagging to close is appropriate.